# Check if Tab on Web Page is selected using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I wanted to do one very simple thing. Does anyone know how can I know if a Tab is selected on web page using selenium RC Python Client?

By tab, I mean the following examples from the following links:
http://clagnut.com/sandbox/csstabs/?writingtext=csstabs#
http://esdi.excelsystems.com/wsexmp/DIVTAB.pgm?wsnum=00096
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/drop-down-menu-30-free-scripts-to-enhance-header-navigation/

I know that I can run `get_eval(js)` with a javascript, where in the javascript might be looking for some change? But I want to know a generic javascript that can tell me if a tab is selected or not? OR is there any Selenium methods that I could just (like `focus()`, etc...)

The reason is because, I can easily click on the tab by calling `click(tab_locator)`. But I want to be sure if I have selected the tab. Isn't there a method like `is_tab_selected(tab_locator)`?

Comment: Can you see the above question -  I want to be sure if I have selected the tab!! Or not just that, I would like to have the ability to find out what all Tabs are selected on a page? Again, I don't expect anything to happen once tab is selected (other than the usual thing of a new section of webpage becoming visible)!!

Answer (score 1):

In pages I test the designer of the page uses a span element for each tab.  When the tab is selected the span class is set to "selected".  I use the following method to verify that a certain tab is selected.

```
def verifySelectedTabName(self, tabText):
    if self.selenium.is_element_present("css=div.'tabheader' span.selected:contains(%s)"%tabText):
        return 1

    return 0
```

In the example pages you reference it looks like the tabs are anchor elements.  You should be able to look for the class name of the anchor. For example,

```
self.selenium.is_element_present("css=div#container1 ul.tabs a.tab-active:contains(%s)"%tabText)
```